# converting from string to int and use it in operation

Tags: react-native

hey guys i got a problem here i have here a text field of number that increment/decrement that depends on the button that is clicked now what i want is to multiply that number to a certain amount and display it but the problem is that the input is being converted to string that is why i cant use as a multiplicant i know that i know to parse it to int but i don't know how someone help me..TIA

```
  class Firstflower extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { textValue:0,amount:0 };
    }

    increment= () =>{
    let a = this.state.textValue;
    const {textValue} = this.setState;  
    this.setState({textValue:a + 1});
    }

    decrement= () =>{
    let a = this.state.textValue;
    const {textValue} = this.setState;  

    this.setState({textValue:a - 1});
    }
    updateText= (text) =>{
    this.setState({textValue: text});
    let a = 2597.50;
    const {amount} = this.setState;
    this.setState({amount:a * parseInt(text)});
    }
```

heres the render code:

```
<View style={styles.labels}>

                    <Text style={styles.movietitle}>Php: 2,597.50</Text>
                <View style={styles.row}>   
                    <Text style={styles.movietext}>Quantity:</Text>

                    <TextInput
                    keyboardType='number-pad'
                    value={this.state.textValue.toString()}
                    onChangeText={this.updateText}
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    />

                    <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.plusminus}
                    onPress={this.increment}>
                    <Text style={styles.plusminustext}>+</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.plusminus}
                    onPress={this.decrement}>
                    <Text style={styles.plusminustext}>-</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                </View> 
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <Text style={styles.movietext}>Amount:</Text>
                    <Text>{`        ${this.state.amount}`}</Text>
                </View>
                </View>
```